# How to easily render partial HTML from a string in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEfPL/1/) tries to render two partials in string form. Of course, this solution won't work (the partials are rendered as-is and not interpreted as angular templates).

From what I understand, I somehow have to use the `$compile` service, but I don't quite get it. For performance reasons, I would like to have each partial only compiled once and then only updated locally. Can `$compile` do that, and if so, how? In my case there are not many partials, not many changes to the set of partials and each partial can be very large (entire sub-page).

And no, I do not want them to be in separate files. Also, the views are lazy-loaded.

Is it maybe even possible to achieve this by inserting a new module for each such partial?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@threed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269061/threed), I was able to fix it all up. [This is an improved version](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/29/) with lazy-loaded content and controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ng-include directive (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/2/) jsfiddle)...

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="partial in partials">
        <div ng-include="partial.name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var data = [
    'data1-apple',
    'data2-banana'
];
var partials = [
    {
        name: 'template1',
        content: '<div>{{data[0]}}</div>'
    },
    {
        name: 'template2',
        content: '<div>{{data[1]}}</div>'
    }
];
function MyCtrl($scope, $templateCache) {
    for(var i in partials){
        $templateCache.put(partials[i].name, partials[i].content);
    }
    $scope.partials = partials;
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

Comment: `$templateCache` to the rescue!